# Как выводить значение в активный инпут

Tags: javascript

я делаю клавиатуру на экране, нужно по ней набрать в два окошка, в один пароль, в другой e-mail, получается только в одно окно писать

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
const input = document.querySelector('input')


buttons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        input.value += btn.innerText
        chars = input.value.split('')
        console.log(chars);
    })
})
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У  меня в html готовые два inputа, в одном нужно ввести email, в другой пароль. Все это нужно ввести клавиатурой, созданной на экране. В js я указала const input = document.querySelector('input'). И ссылаясь на input, он дает мне возможность писать только в окошке с email. Как сделать так что бы можно  было писать и в окне с email и с паролем

Comment: У вас же написано `document.querySelector('input')`, почитайте как определить активный `input` и выводить данные именно в него